# Postgres 9.6 fetch key value pair from text field

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres table where column named 'arguments' (type text) contains below text:

```
testdb=> select arguments from table_name;
  
   arguments
----------------------------------------------------
 array (                                           +
   'description' => array (                        +
     'country' => 'USA',                           +
     'state' => 'california',                      +
     'zip' => '12345',                             +
     'x' => 'y',                                   +
   ),                                              +
 )
(1 row)
```

How do I select individual key value pair in a select query. Say I want to extract only state and zip.

Comment: What is that, the serialisation of a PHP associative array? It's unlikely you will be able to process this in Postgres.

Comment: You should not store this as `text` in the first place. Use `jsonb` instead.

Comment: Yes it is a serialised PHP associative array.